# Unable to create instance on Google Cloud - The "zone..." does not have enough resources

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am neither able to create an instance on gcloud compute nor my application on gcloud app engine able to pull instances. Our application is down since yesterday. I observed that it can be specific to my project. When I created a new account and tried from that its working fine. Please advise. I don't want to move to a different account as this already have my company funds.

Comment: Can you successfully create an instance without an external IP address?

Comment: Yes. I am able to create an instance in the same region without External IP Address. Please advise further steps.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance first without an external IP address. One method of doing this is to add the flag `--no-address` in statement

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-name --no-address
```

Step 2. 
Go to VPC Networking -> External IP addresses. Create an external IP address and associate it with the instance you're attempting to make. Once they're created you're good to go. The operation may fail but is easier to be repeated than manually launching instances over an over.

This will not resolve issues with Flex Deployments/Dataflow etc.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using compute directly. Is there any way to configure that instance in my app engine application through app.yaml?

Comment: No. Alternatively find a region you can launch instances in, and create a new project and GAE application in that region and deploy there. Sorry it's just a workaround not a solution.